# How to make image pixels in UIImageView be transparent?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have Image.png (**it has some transparent pixels**) in ImageView, but when i run my app on device, **pixels** on my Image **are not transparent** (i dont see anything below image, i see just gray color in this places). Have anybody know can I make it work?

Comment: Did you set a background color on the `UIImageView`?

Comment: Today i created new project with same imageview and image... and everything was fine. Due to this fact i can say that problem was in project settings, but were i can't understad. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Change your UIImageView's background color to clear color using this:

```
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I had set this parameter in interface builder. I try to run app on iphone simulator and it work good, but when i try to run app on real device - problem ther. I create some screenshots [link](http://depositfiles.com/files/huizjizmx)

Comment: You must also turn off the "opaque" setting in IB for the image view.

Comment: Opaque is off too... Problem in somthing else.